# How can I use a column value in a subquery without selecting (displaying) it in the main query?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

How could I use the following query without displaying the au_id from the authors table? I know that I need it for the join but I don't want it displayed.

EDIT: I am using the pubs database

```
SELECT a.au_id, 
       NAME, 
       Substring(title, 1, 25)        AS title, 
       type, 
       Format(pubdate, 'MMM dd yyyy') AS pubdate 
FROM   (SELECT au_id, 
               ( au_fname + ' ' + au_lname ) AS NAME, 
               phone 
        FROM   authors AS au) AS a 
       JOIN titleauthor ta 
         ON a.au_id = ta.au_id 
       JOIN titles t 
         ON ta.title_id = t.title_id 
WHERE  t.title_id IN (SELECT title_id 
                      FROM   roysched) 
ORDER  BY NAME
```

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, great formatting, it's so much easier to read now! (How can people write SQL impossible to read?!?)

Comment: @jarth, thanks but I just copy paste to http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza that sqlformatter site is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it from the field list in the outter select. You need it in the inner select so can use it on the join. But not on the select list

Change

```
 SELECT a.au_id,  NAME, ...
```

for

```
 SELECT NAME, ...
```

Comment: That's really embarrassing, I had been trying to do that and SQL management studio was giving me invalid column errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  (au_fname + ' ' + au_lname ) AS NAME, 
         Substring(title, 1, 25)     AS title,
         type, 
         Format(pubdate, 'MMM dd yyyy') AS pubdate       
FROM   authors AS a 
JOIN titleauthor ta ON a.au_id = ta.au_id 
JOIN titles t  ON ta.title_id = t.title_id 
WHERE  t.title_id IN (SELECT title_id FROM roysched) 
ORDER  BY a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname
```